# Can't able to print only search result after scrape search result

Tags: php, web-scraping, domparser

I am using [Simple Html Dom](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) .I am new in web scraping, i am scraping data from booking.com i having problem with printing only the search result URL.My code bellow

```
<?php

    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $searchText = "Venice";
    $searchText = str_replace(" ", "+", $searchText);

    $url = "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=1781605&lang=en-gb&sid=3bb432f656e368125330f71ea0e74e36&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https://www.booking.com/index.en-gb.html?aid=1781605;sid=3bb432f656e368125330f71ea0e74e36;sb_price_type=total;srpvid=dc2798d544dd007f&;&ss=".$searchText."&is_ski_area=0&ssne=".$searchText."&ssne_untouched=".$searchText."&dest_id=-132007&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2019&checkin_month=5&checkin_monthday=19&checkout_year=2019&checkout_month=5&checkout_monthday=20&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1";


    print $url."<br>";


    $html = file_get_html($url);

    $i = 0;

    $linkObjs = $html->find('a');

    foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
        
        $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

        /*if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/^hotel/', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
            $link = matches[1];
        } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) {
            continue;
        }*/

        if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) {
            continue;
        }

        $i++;

        echo "Link: ". $link . "<br/><hr/>";

    }
?>
```

Now the problem is i want to print the search result link which have `/hotel/` path in URL like `https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/nh-collection-venezia-palazzo-barocci.en-gb.html` now i don't understand how to setup `preg_replace` for print only the search result URL also the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `^` in an expression means asserting the start of the string which you test for in the second clause:

```
if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/^hotel/', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
```

If you want to use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you could use a single expression to check if the string starts with http with an optional s:

```
^https?://.*?/hotel/
```

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match `http`, optional `s`, `://`
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `/hotel/` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xEu1Vs/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/fkmPb)

For example:

```
if (!preg_match('~^https?://.*?/hotel~', $link)) {
    continue;
}
```

Without using a regex you could also use a combination of [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (!(substr($link, 0, 4 ) === "http" && strpos($link, '/hotel/') !== false)) {
    continue;
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IOvfn)